# Can't run Android app in 5.x devices

Tags: android, android-support-library

I can run my in 4.x devices, but not in 5.x. This is my `build.gradle`'s relevant parts:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'

    //Butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'

    //Dagger2
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

Compilation is ok, but when I run the app I get this error in Android 5.x devices:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class
>   loader; no stack available

I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it! I have modified this:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
```

I must have any dependency that requires a lower version of the Android Plugin for Gradle...